# PostgreSQL: Speed up multiple JOINs of one big table with many small tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, query-optimization

I am trying to speed up my PostgreSQL reporting query. I simplyfied the data model for better understanding.

My reporting query uses the following tables:

- 1 big table with ~500.000 rows. This can easily grow to millions of rows.
- ~20 small tables with each ~20 rows. They just contain texts getting added to the big table.

The **big table** looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table (
    id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    attr_1_id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    attr_2_id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    attr_3_id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT big_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And the **small tables** all look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE small_table_1 (
    id character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    language_id character(2) NOT NULL,
    text character varying(100),
    CONSTRAINT small_table_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The **query** looks like this:

```
SELECT
    big_table.attr_1_id,
    small_table_1.text,

    big_table.attr_2_id,
    small_table_2.text,

    big_table.attr_3_id,
    small_table_3.text,

    ...
    
FROM big_table

LEFT JOIN small_table_1
ON small_table_1.id = big_table.attr_id_1
AND small_table_1.language_id = 'DE' 

LEFT JOIN small_table_2
ON small_table_2.id = big_table.attr_id_2
AND small_table_2.language_id = 'DE'

LEFT JOIN small_table_3
ON small_table_3.id = big_table.attr_id_3
AND small_table_3.language_id = 'DE'

...
```

With ~500.000 rows in the big table every `LEFT JOIN` already takes ~200ms.
So with millions of rows and many small tables to join the execution time grows quickly.

In the query planner each `LEFT JOIN` looks like this:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=31.94..13727.27 rows=432242 width=148) (actual time=4.398..581.194 rows=432242 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: ((small_table_1.id)::text = (big_table.attr_id_1)::text)
```

Here is the complete real query plan. I still had to remove the `LEFT JOIN`s of 10 small tables to not hit the Stack Overflow max character limit of 30,000.

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Hash Left Join  (cost=208.64..400076.38 rows=460222 width=3163) (actual time=7.508..7178.265 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".employment_status_id)::text = (estx.id)::text)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=8290"
"  CTE q2"
"    ->  Seq Scan on cust_group  (cost=0.00..13.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  InitPlan 3 (returns $2)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2 q2_1  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  InitPlan 4 (returns $3)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2 q2_2  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  InitPlan 5 (returns $4)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2 q2_3  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"  InitPlan 6 (returns $5)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2 q2_4  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  InitPlan 7 (returns $6)"
"    ->  CTE Scan on q2 q2_5  (cost=0.00..6.00 rows=300 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=158.57..338963.78 rows=460222 width=2513) (actual time=6.695..4724.369 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (((NULL::character varying))::text = (citx.id)::text)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=8289"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=156.37..337727.90 rows=460222 width=2490) (actual time=5.361..4492.058 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (""*SELECT* 1"".action_type_id = attx.id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=8288"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=155.00..336492.84 rows=460222 width=2478) (actual time=3.754..4261.646 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".job_id)::text = (jbtx.id)::text)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=8287"
"                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=128.25..335232.41 rows=460222 width=2457) (actual time=1.704..4048.729 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".employee_type_id)::text = (ettx.id)::text)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=8264"
"                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=126.96..333997.44 rows=460222 width=2239) (actual time=0.642..3788.566 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=8263"
"                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=126.81..328236.49 rows=460222 width=2222) (actual time=0.622..3478.490 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=8261"
"                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=126.67..322475.55 rows=460222 width=2205) (actual time=0.612..3155.816 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".org_unit_id)::text = (outx.id)::text)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=8259"
"                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=98.98..321214.18 rows=460222 width=2185) (actual time=0.541..2969.331 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".cost_center_id)::text = (cctx.id)::text)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=8236"
"                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=96.93..319978.45 rows=460222 width=2175) (actual time=0.519..2712.470 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: (coat.country_id = (cutx.id)::bpchar)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=8235"
"                                                        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=83.59..313061.78 rows=460222 width=2163) (actual time=0.412..2404.622 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                              Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".company_id)::text = (cotx.id)::text)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=8231"
"                                                              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=71.45..311815.96 rows=460222 width=1945) (actual time=0.382..2131.789 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Hash Cond: ((NULL::bpchar) = (crtx_le.id)::bpchar)"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=8230"
"                                                                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=61.14..305017.38 rows=460222 width=1928) (actual time=0.298..1886.031 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=8227"
"                                                                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=60.99..299256.43 rows=460222 width=1896) (actual time=0.282..1584.799 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".employee_id)::text = (emat.id)::text)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=8225"
"                                                                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=47.75..298019.21 rows=460222 width=1871) (actual time=0.131..1287.387 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Hash Cond: (""*SELECT* 1"".scenario_id = scen.id)"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=8219"
"                                                                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=46.70..296784.48 rows=460222 width=1853) (actual time=0.122..1026.567 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Hash Cond: (""*SELECT* 1"".action_id = aclg.action_id)"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=8218"
"                                                                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=38.02..292886.93 rows=460222 width=1789) (actual time=0.046..883.004 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Hash Cond: ((""*SELECT* 1"".company_id)::text = (coat.id)::text)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=8212"
"                                                                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=21.05..291645.36 rows=460222 width=1773) (actual time=0.035..712.011 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Hash Cond: ((NULL::bpchar) = (conv_gr.from_currency_id)::bpchar)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=8211"
"                                                                                                        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..285204.21 rows=460222 width=1742) (actual time=0.013..465.417 rows=493850 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=8209"
"                                                                                                              ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 1""  (cost=0.00..2739.92 rows=68841 width=178) (actual time=0.012..55.052 rows=68841 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=1191"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on appl_plan_headcount  (cost=0.00..1879.41 rows=68841 width=150) (actual time=0.010..32.481 rows=68841 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=1191"
"                                                                                                              ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 2""  (cost=3405.85..280163.18 rows=391381 width=151) (actual time=36.277..350.251 rows=425009 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=7018"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Gather  (cost=3405.85..274292.47 rows=391381 width=95) (actual time=36.275..231.496 rows=425009 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Workers Planned: 2"
"                                                                                                                          Workers Launched: 2"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=7018"
"                                                                                                                          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=2405.85..234154.37 rows=163075 width=95) (actual time=26.658..228.421 rows=141670 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                                                Hash Cond: ((co.scenario_id = hc.scenario_id) AND ((co.employee_id)::text = (hc.employee_id)::text) AND (co.cal_year_month_id = hc.cal_year_month_id) AND (co.action_id = hc.action_id))"
"                                                                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=7018"
"                                                                                                                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on appl_plan_costs co  (cost=0.00..7464.01 rows=180101 width=45) (actual time=0.007..52.792 rows=144081 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=5663"
"                                                                                                                                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1595.95..1595.95 rows=40495 width=62) (actual time=25.189..25.189 rows=22947 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                                                      Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8096kB"
"                                                                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=1191"
"                                                                                                                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on appl_plan_headcount hc  (cost=0.00..1595.95 rows=40495 width=62) (actual time=0.009..10.810 rows=22947 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=1191"
"                                                                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=21.00..21.00 rows=4 width=48) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                              ->  Seq Scan on cust_currency_conversion conv_gr  (cost=0.00..21.00 rows=4 width=48) (actual time=0.011..0.013 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Filter: ((to_currency_id)::text = ($4)::text)"
"                                                                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 6"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=13.10..13.10 rows=310 width=234) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                                                                        ->  Seq Scan on appl_company_attr coat  (cost=0.00..13.10 rows=310 width=234) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                                                            ->  Hash  (cost=7.50..7.50 rows=94 width=72) (actual time=0.070..0.072 rows=91 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                                                                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3.18..7.50 rows=94 width=72) (actual time=0.016..0.053 rows=91 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Hash Cond: ((aclg.created_by)::text = (ausr.id)::text)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                                                                                                        ->  Seq Scan on appl_plan_action_log aclg  (cost=0.00..3.94 rows=94 width=58) (actual time=0.003..0.013 rows=91 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=3.08..3.08 rows=8 width=24) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=5 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                              ->  Seq Scan on auth_user ausr  (cost=0.00..3.08 rows=8 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=5 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=22) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on appl_scenarios scen  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=22) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                                                ->  Hash  (cost=9.22..9.22 rows=322 width=31) (actual time=0.146..0.146 rows=370 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 33kB"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on appl_employee_attr emat  (cost=0.00..9.22 rows=322 width=31) (actual time=0.005..0.057 rows=370 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=6"
"                                                                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..8.18 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=493850)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                ->  Index Scan using cust_currency_conversion_pkey on cust_currency_conversion conv_ta  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Index Cond: (((from_currency_id)::text = ($5)::text) AND ((to_currency_id)::text = 'USD'::text))"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=7.88..7.88 rows=195 width=21) (actual time=0.080..0.081 rows=195 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on appl_currency_text crtx_le  (cost=0.00..7.88 rows=195 width=21) (actual time=0.007..0.051 rows=195 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                                                                Rows Removed by Filter: 195"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=12.12..12.12 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on appl_company_text cotx  (cost=0.00..12.12 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=10.23..10.23 rows=249 width=16) (actual time=0.102..0.102 rows=249 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on appl_country_text cutx  (cost=0.00..10.23 rows=249 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.064 rows=249 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 249"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.70..1.70 rows=28 width=20) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=28 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on appl_cost_center_text cctx  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=28 width=20) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=28 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 28"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=26.12..26.12 rows=125 width=29) (actual time=0.065..0.066 rows=125 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=23"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on appl_org_unit_text outx  (cost=0.00..26.12 rows=125 width=29) (actual time=0.004..0.046 rows=125 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 125"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=23"
"                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=493850)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using appl_currency_text_pkey on appl_currency_text crtx_gr  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (((id)::text = ($6)::text) AND (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar))"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=493850)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using appl_currency_text_pkey on appl_currency_text crtx_ta  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Index Cond: (((id)::text = 'USD'::text) AND (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar))"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.27..1.27 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=0.503..0.504 rows=11 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on appl_employee_type_text ettx  (cost=0.00..1.27 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=11 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 11"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=25.50..25.50 rows=100 width=29) (actual time=0.706..0.707 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=23"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on appl_job_text jbtx  (cost=0.00..25.50 rows=100 width=29) (actual time=0.004..0.047 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 100"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=23"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=1.25..1.25 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=0.409..0.410 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on appl_action_type_text attx  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 10"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1.80..1.80 rows=32 width=26) (actual time=0.360..0.360 rows=32 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"              ->  Seq Scan on appl_cost_item_text citx  (cost=0.00..1.80 rows=32 width=26) (actual time=0.008..0.015 rows=32 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 32"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=1 width=296) (actual time=0.418..0.419 rows=2 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1"
"        ->  Seq Scan on appl_employment_status_text estx  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=296) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (language_id = 'DE'::bpchar)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 2"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"Planning Time: 2.079 ms"
"Execution Time: 7247.830 ms"
```

Almost 80 % of the time is spent on the `LEFT JOIN`s.

[image: Statistics per Node Type]

More information:

- PostgreSQL 12.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
- I configured enough `work_mem` so nothing happens on disc.
- According to the query planner a `Hash Left Join` is used which should already be the quickest.
- From my understanding using an index will not help because all rows from the big table are read and half of the rows from each small table are read because there are currently only two languages (DE, EN).
- A poor try was to `UNION` all small tables first because they all have the same column structure. Then I did a `LEFT JOIN` of the result multiple times. But no improvement.

Is there any way to speed this up? Like [parallel hash joins](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/parallel-hash-joins-postgresql-explained)? How does that work? Or is setting other parameters an option?

Comment: The first step to tuning a real query is looking at a real query plan.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the _complete_ execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` -  not just the part you think is interesting. Ideally with `track_io_timing` turned on.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: I have added the real query plan, the statistics per node type and the Postgres version to the question

Comment: `LEFT JOIN small_table_1
ON small_table_1.id = big_table.attr_id_1` <<-- this looks like a JOIN on a FK->PK. Are there indexes on both sides? (also: you seem to have text fields as keys, and **very** large row sizes)

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestion: Experiment with one or two small tables and the big table. [Edit] your question, or write another, to show us the definitions,indexes, and row counts of those tables as well as the query plan. Objective: better indexes on the small tables if possible. Observation: hash joins are a reasonable strategy for the kind of name lookup you do with your small tables. That's how you would do the same thing in an application program.

Comment: Are you selecting all rows from the big table or is there some where clause restricting the rows? If there is a where clause, please show it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: All rows from the big tables are selected. There is no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @wildplasser: I experimented with indexes on both sides. The query always uses a Seq Scan. When I switch off Seq Scan PostgreSQL starts using Bitmap Index Scan or Bitmap Heap Scan but the time for the `JOIN`s stays the same. - Text fields as keys are used because the user can upload his own data to both tables. The IDs to the big table and the according text to the small table. Does int as key make a performance difference? - The large row size is interesting. I will dig further into that. But even when I run a minimal version of the query and width stays low the `JOIN`s take the same time.

Comment: I have added the table definitions to the question.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance you must do these options:

1. Create an index for fields which using in where clause
2. Create an index for fields used in the join condition. For example: `small_table_1.id = big_table.attr_id_1`. Here field `id` may be a primary key, but you must create an index for field `attr_id_1`
3. ***From my understanding using an index will not help because all rows are read.*** - No, indexes are very important, you should definitely use indexes. Indexes increase performance on the process of the joining table and filtering data.

**ATTENTION!!! ATTENTION!!!**
I accidentally saw one bad code on your query plan, this is very bad for the performance.

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=31.94..13727.27 rows=432242 width=148) (actual time=4.398..581.194 rows=432242 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: ((small_table_1.id)::text = (big_table.attr_id_1)::text)
```

The database automatically converted id fields to text type, why? This is will very very decrease your performance. May be `small_table_1.id` and `big_table.attr_id_1` types are difference. Please control all table's id field types. These fields must be the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!
- No `WHERE` clause is used. All rows from the big table are read. No filtering data.
- I played around with indexes for the fields used in the `JOIN` condition in the big table and in the small table. No effect.
- The fields used in the join conditions are `VARCHAR` because the user can upload his own IDs for these fields. They get casted from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`. I changed the column type in both tables from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` so no type cast will be done in the `JOIN`. No effect. Will `INTEGER` as ID make a big performance difference?

Comment: Excellent. I'm happy for you. But I have some recommendations for you.  integer very faster than varchar or text.  That's why, if you can, so change ID field types to an integer. If you search the internet yourself, you will see that everywhere recommended integer type for ID fields. Don't forget creating primary keys for ID fields and  normal index  for  fields `attr_id_1`, `attr_id_2`..... on the big_table

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't use integer for the IDs. - The ID fields are primary keys and I created indexes for fields `attr_id_1`, `attr_id_2`... in the big table. None of this had an effect on the query performance.